# I need populate child work item whenever the parent work item created

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-devops-services

If I have a epic work item named "capitalized", whenever a epic created with this name its child should autopopulated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, this feature was not supported yet in Azure Devops, you could create a logic app to help realize this feature. And you could refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/quickstart-create-first-logic-app-workflow) for more information.